# Property can not be null on Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

```
<Style TargetType="controls:EventTimeView">      
    <Style.Triggers>         
        <Trigger Property="PositioningMethod" Value="Column" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

PositioningMethod is a dependency property of EventTimeView of an enum type.

Results in:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
Message=Property can not be null on Trigger.
Source=PresentationFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateTables(PropertyValue& propertyValue, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalStructList`1& triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalStructList`1& resourceDependents, HybridDictionary& dataTriggerRecordFromBinding, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildName, Boolean& hasInstanceValues)
InnerException:
```

I have no idea what might be wrong. The exception is too vague: which property? what is null?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Double check your DependencyProperty definition for PositioningMethodProperty - make sure the owning type is in fact the class in which the DP is defined.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error because I was using `Trigger` instead of `DataTrigger` and I was binding the trigger to a property in the data context and not to a property in the control per se.

Once I changed the `Trigger` tag to `DataTrigger`, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background property beforehand in the style like:

```
    <Style TargetType="controls:EventTimeView">   
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

    <Style.Triggers>         
        <Trigger Property="PositioningMethod" Value="Column" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```